# cronでphpファイルを実行すると作成されるファイルのパーミッションが644になる

Tags: linux, cron

Amazon Linuxでcrontabの設定をしてcronを実行すると作成されるファイルのパーミッションが644になります。作成されるファイルが664にしたいのですが、Linuxのどの設定を変更すればいいでしょうか。phpファイル内でパーミッション、umaskを指定すればできますがLinuxの設定で変更したいです。

cron実行ユーザのumaskを002に変更しても、cron実行後に作成されるファイルがパーミッション644になってしまいます。

cronを通してphpファイルが実行されて作成されるファイルが、なぜ最初に設定したumask002にならないのかがわかりません。

crontab

```
27 01 * * * /usr/bin/php /aaa/index.php
```

index.php

```
<?php
    $file = "/data/bbb.txt";
    $string = "Hello, PHP";
    file_put_contents($file, $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

cron 実行時はログインシェルは動かないので cron実行ユーザの profile 等に設定した内容は読み込まれません。実行時の umask や必要な環境変数は、 crontab に明示的に書けば良いと思いますので試してみてください。

```
27 01 * * * umask 0002; /usr/bin/php /aaa/index.php
```

もしくは、pam で cron実行時のデフォルトのumaskを設定しても効果があるかもです。
ファイル `/etc/pam.d/crond`

```
session optional pam_umask.so umask=0002
```